# Windows Resisting Connection to Host

Tags: network-shares, windows-networking

This may be YAWF<sup>TM</sup> (Yet Another Windows Failure) but I have to ask **yet again** how to get Windows to observe its configuration.

A Windows 10 laptop is configured to connect to local machines variously by Ethernet (on one subnet) or WiFi (on another subnet), for user convenience.  Network locations and drive letter mappings are duly created to shares on other Windows machines and Samba servers.  The Samba servers in particular have Ethernet adapters on each of the two subnets.

Sadly, the laptop only connects to the Samba servers when connected to the WiFi subnet and not when connected to the Ethernet subnet.  This, notwithstanding that the hostname is identical, the machines can ping one another on the Ethernet subnet, and c:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts expressly identifies the hostname at IP addresses on each of the two subnets. It seems sublimely odd that a named share on a named machine should not simply connect, unless, of course, the share is deceptively contingent upon subnet or IP address.  If this is so, then that calls the entire Windows networking stack into question unless a double-secret / nonobvious hack exists to get it to behave.

So, the question is, what configuration will Windows observe so as to be agnostic about how it connects to a share?

Comment: You need to add a schema of your network architecture. And how does the laptop connect to these two networks.

Comment: @harrymc, thanks.  The server is 192.168.1.2 on the Ethernet subnet and 192.168.2.2 on the WiFi subnet.  The laptop is 192.168.1.4 on E, 192.168.2.4 on W.  The WiFi router's WAN IP is 192.168.1.14 on E and its LAN IP is 192.168.2.1 (*i.e.*, it's the GW for the WiFi subnet and behind the edge router at 192.168.1.1, which is to isolate the WiFi subnet).  How the laptop connects is described in the OP, *i.e.*, via Ethernet and WiFi on the two subnets.  The question isn't about network architecture, however, which is a given and well understood, but Windows configuration.